# How to ensure my confirm checkbox is ticked before allowing submission of my form

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, checkbox

Once again the novice JS is back again with a question.  I want a confirmation tickbox at the end of my form before allowing the user to send me their details and if it's not ticked then they can't submit the form. I've had a look on here and tried using different examples of coding but I just find it all very confusing after looking at 10 or 20 pages of different code. Here is what I've written so far, from what I can make out my form just skips over my checkbox validation code which is obviously what I don't want to happen:

```
<head>
<script>
function validate (){
  send = document.getElementById("confirm").value;

  errors = "";

  if (send.checked == false){
    errors += "Please tick the checkbox as confirmation your details are correct \n";
    } else if (errors == ""){
      alert ("Your details are being sent)
    } else {
        alert(errors);
    }  
  }
</script>
</head>

<body>
  <div>      
    <label for="confirm" class="fixedwidth">Yes I confirm all my details are correct</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="confirm" id="confirm"/>
  </div>
  <div class="button">
    <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" onclick="validate()"/>
  </div>
```

Comment: Look at the following tutorial and focus on the usage of the `onsubmit` event. [Form validation](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/javascript_form_validations.htm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are making `send` be `confirm`'s value.

```
send = document.getElementById("confirm").value;
```

This way `send.checked` will not work. Because you are trying to get the attribute `checked` from a value (probably, string).

For the correct use, try this:

```
send = document.getElementById("confirm");
sendValue = send.value;
sendCheck = send.checked;
```

Then you can test with

```
if (sendCheck == false){ //sendCheck  evaluate true if checkbox is checked, false if not.
```

To stop form from submitting, `return false;` after the error alerts.

Here the complete code - **updated to work correctly** (considering the `<form>` tag has id `tesForm`):

```
 document.getElementById("testForm").onsubmit = function () {
    var send = document.getElementById("confirm"),
        sendValue = send.value,
        sendCheck = send.checked,
        errors = "";

    //validate checkbox
    if (!sendCheck) {
        errors += "Please tick the checkbox as confirmation your details are correct \n";
    }


    //validate other stuff here




    //in case you added more error types above
    //stacked all errors and in the end, show them
    if (errors != "") {
        alert(errors);
        return false; //if return, below code will not run
    }

    //passed all validations, then it's ok
    alert("Your details are being sent"); // <- had a missing " after sent.
    return true; //will submit
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RaphaelDDL/gHNAf/

Comment: This won't stop the form from being submitted.

Comment: Thanks for your input and it's nearly there. If I tick the checkbox its submits the form which is good but if I leave the checkbox blank it just reloads the page and starts again with a blank form, no error message.

Comment: @Steve Okay, fixed the code and added example. This new approach is better for reading, you don't need lots of `if - else if`

Comment: Excellent, thanks very much for your advice and showing me the example. As an inexperienced writer I find sometimes the answers on here can be vague/confusing to people like me who are just starting

Comment: @Steve I know that feeling. I always try to comment my answers to help. If you don't understand something, let me know :)

Answer (score 2):

I would just enable/disable your button based on the checkbox state. Add an ID to your button, (i'll pretend the submit button has an id of `btnSubmit`)

```
document.getElementById("confirm").onchange = function() {
    document.getElementById("btnSubmit").disabled = !this.checked;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tymeJV/hQ8hF/1

Answer (score 0):

You don't need javascript to do this. [All modern browsers](https://caniuse.com/#feat=form-validation) have native form validation built in. If you mark the checkbox as **required**, the form will not submit unless it is checked.

```
<form>
  <input type="checkbox" required=""/>
  <button type="submit">Done</button>
</form>
```